# How to read line by line from a file and execute inner contents

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

How do I read contents from a file line by line with spaces and execute a portion of that line

For example I have the following in my file

```
Hello world $(echo 9923,3443,434,344 | cut -d"," -f4)
Hello world $(echo 9923,3443,434,344 | cut -d"," -f2)
Hello world $(echo 9923,3443,434,344 | cut -d"," -f1)
```

My Expected result would be

```
Hello world 344
Hello world 3443
Hello world 9223
```

What I get is by echoing in a while loop

```
Hello world $(echo 9923,3443,434,344 | cut -d"," -f4)
Hello world $(echo 9923,3443,434,344 | cut -d"," -f2)
Hello world $(echo 9923,3443,434,344 | cut -d"," -f1)
```

My code will be something like

```
while read LINE
do
     echo $LINE
done < FILE
```

I have tried several things like using backticks,double quotes,eval nothing seems to work.

Comment: in ksh, `print -- " Hello world $(echo 9923,3443,434,344 | cut -d"," -f4) "  | while read line ; do eval echo $line ; done` works for me (as a close approximation of your problem). As you say you've used `eval` and its not working, is it possible that you are mixing OS's and trying to process an MS=DOS generated file in Unix. if so, `dos2unix FILE` may help. Well structured question, keep posting! Good luck.

Comment: @shelter your solution works fine as well,I was having special characters in the file such as &.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
while read line; do
    eval "echo $line";
done < FILE
```

Comment: It didn't work I get only the first part "Hello", looks like its breaking in to several line because of space

Comment: @Yuvi It's strange because I tested it in bash, zsh ans plain sh. Works fine in all cases.

Comment: Hi this works fine what went wrong is I was using & character in that line.

Comment: is there any solution if the line contains special characters such as &.

Comment: I'm fairly new to shell scripting,what do you mean by escaping?